# How to determine absolute file path of a Java source file in Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my custom Eclipse plugin, I have the fully qualified class name of a Java class as a String, and want to know its actual file path. In fact, I want to know the name of the source folder it resides in.

The class could be from any of the Java projects in the Workspace. The source folder names are arbitrary.

I use Eclipse 3.6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use the search engine API.  See `org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine`.

You can see that there are various static functions you can call, each with their own options.  You will need to create an appropriate `org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchPattern` and then pass it to the search engine along with a scope (the workspace) and a requestor (something that gathers all of the results).

Typically, you will get a bunch of stuff back, like `IType`s, which are the public API for accessing types in the Java model.  You can call `IType.getResource().getLocation()` to get the filesystem location of any type.  The getResource method may return null, so you need to check for that.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds very promising. I will be able to try that on Monday, and let you know if it works. Can you recommend a particular `SearchEngine` method?

Comment: The Open Type dialog (Control+Shift+T) Uses the same SearchEngine.

Comment: @Ravi Yes, that's what I was hoping! Btw, can I simply create a new instance of the `SearchEngine` class, or do I need to get it from some Eclipse factory?

Comment: You instantiate SearchEngine by calling one of its static methods.

Comment: Okay, it finally worked. The API takes some getting used to, but that's not your fault.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the [JDT API stuff](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_int_model.htm) to get to the `IResource` of the Java class. From there you can use the Resource API to get the containing folders and whatever else you need.